# Closing Send Mail Window after Canceling Item Send event within Outlook via VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm coding a VBA Macro to prevent sending emails to a specified email address. It's an Outlook Macro which runs under the ThisOutlookSession. Code runs fine, but the problem is that I can't close the **Send Mail** window.

I added a line (marked in the code) which throws an error that *"**The Item.Close command cannot be performed during Item.Send event**"*

It's understandble, but how can I overcome this?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

 If Item.To = "some@domain.com" Then
     Prompt$ = "Are you sure you want to send this message?"
   If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check before Sending") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True

    Item.Close olDiscard          ' <<< ERROR HERE 

  End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of closing the Item itself which can't be done when the send event is still running you close the `Item Inspector`.

See below:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim objInsp As Inspector
Dim Strmsg As String
Set objInsp = Item.GetInspector
If Item.To = "testmail@gmail.com" Then
    Strmsg = "Are you sure you want to send this message?"
    If MsgBox(Strmsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check before Sending") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
        objInsp.Close 1
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Very useful, I tried to close it with using inspector but in a different way which didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In languages other than VBA, you can use a timer - enable the timer in the ItemSend event, when the timer event fires (you will be out of the ItemSend event handler by then), disable the time and close the inspector.

I don't think you can use a timer in Outlook VBA though...